# Get usermeta info from sql query

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I'm using WooCommerce and need to get my users billing name, billing address, billing phone, billing email, etc from wp_usermeta in a good format like this:

```
name,address,phone,email
fake name, 123 stackexchange rd,111-111-1111,email@email.com
```

Anyone know how to do something like this?
I need to do it for alot of users (10k+) in one go if possible. I tried using some php code but it didnt work. Any help appreciated

Comment: Please tell what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use meta_query to specify what conditions you want to meet with that query you are performing. i.e.:

```
// grab some record from DB with a specific meta query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'woo_commerce_something' ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_something_woo_commerce_email',
            'value' => 'email@email@email.com'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        // do something 
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```